# Can two hosts at different networks have same mac address

Tags: mac-address

can there be two  different hosts at two different networks with same MAC address.
is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, yes. There can be two identical MAC addresses on two different LANS, certainly, and it will still work as expected / as if they were different, no problem. However, if there were two identical MAC addresses on the same LAN, there would be issues, because that's how they are supposed to be uniquely identified on the same network. Hope this helps (and is right, I'm always self-conscious about posting here lol)